# Batch Apex - SOAP Callout Issue

Tags: apex, batch, callout, soap

We have implemented a batch Apex solution for mass update records. More specifically, we upload a CSV file (more or less 2500 records) in a custom object and we "read" this CSV to create some child records of this object. After this step, a SOAP callout is performed for every record. There are some cases in this callout that randomly in some records the request is like it "gets cut" or it becomes invalid. We do not have UTF Encoding. For example, i get an error

- System.CalloutException The following exception has occured: IO Exception: Unableto tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1.503 Service Unavailable"
  What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you checked at the server team (where the SOAP service is hosted) if there are any errors seen at their end? Since, this happens intermittently, this may be because of overloading or network issues or firewall limitations at their end.

Comment: We have checked it and the problem is that the request is invalid. It is not complete. But it is random. I mean, if i send it again for the same record, the request is complete.

Comment: By this `the problem is that the request is invalid`, do you mean that random requests sent from SF was invalid/ incomplete and hence, the web server rejected it?

Comment: Yes, this is the issue.

Comment: This could be a temporary service-side Salesforce issue or it might be your client. If you can reproduce the SOAP call issue with a non-Salesforce client, then you'd have a stronger case for  Salesforce being the root cause and you should open a support ticket.